# How do I pull the values of attributes for each element, that are in XML file?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xml-parsing

I have this XML schemal file and I am trying to find a way to automatically pull the attribute values for each element.

Comment: Is your code not working?  Maybe you can tell us what you get as a result of your code.

Comment: I would use xsd.exe to create classes from schema.  You can then delete from the classes what you do not want.

Comment: Don't mix usage of the old DOM `XmlDocument` and the new one `XDocument` you can just load the file directly into the `XDocument`.  Also don't call `ToString` on an element just to turn around and parse the string back into an element object.

Comment: Right now, It's not really give me any results, so that's why i was wondering how can  the code be better improved. The aim is to just the values of the attributes and export that into a CSV file.

Comment: @juharr, I am not quite getting what your suggestion are. Do you mind showing it?

Comment: `var xdocument = XDocument.Load(@"D:\New Text Document.xsd");` to load the file and instead of `var xml = XElement.Parse(scopeNode.ToString());` and using `xml` just use `scopeNode`.